# Ordering by avg on a tag list

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a tagging system on my site an clicking on a tag will take you to a list associated of batsmen associated with that tag. I want to order these batsmen on the avg rating score they have been given by users who have review them. How would i do this?

My tables:

- Batsmen : id, name, Country_id,
- Reviews: id, rating, comment
- tag: id, tagname
- Batsmen_tag: batsmen_id, Tag_id(many to many table)

Currently i am just finding tag($id) in my controller and using a foreach with the relationship to bring back batsmen related to that tag, for example

```
@foreach($tag->batsmen as $tags)

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$batsmen = $batsmen->each( function ($item, $key) {
    $item->average_rating = $item->reviews->avg('rating');
});

$sorted = $batsmen->sortBy('average_rating');
```

Comment: where does the tag fit in to this ?

Comment: put that inside your foreach and just update `$batsmen` to `$tags`